# Python Error :'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have written a code in python to generate a sequence of ARIMA model's and determine their AIC values to compare them.The code is as below,

```
p=0
q=0
d=0

for p in range(5):
    for d in range(1):
        for q in range(4):
            arima_mod=sm.tsa.ARIMA(df,(p,d,q)).fit()
            print(arima_mod.params)
            print arima_mod.aic()
```

I am getting a error message as below,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-b662b0c42796> in <module>()
      8             arima_mod=sm.tsa.ARIMA(df,(p,d,q)).fit()
      9             print(arima_mod.params)
---> 10             print arima_mod.aic()
        global arima_mod.aic = 1262.2449736558815
     11 

**TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable**
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the brackets after `print arima_mod.aic()`. As I read it, `arima_mod.aic` is `1262.2449736558815`, and thus a float. The brackets make python think it is a function, and tries to call it. You do not want that (because it breaks), you just want that value. So remove the brackets, and you'll be fine.